# finding all rings of order $p^3$

Tags: finite-rings

Classify all commutative rings with $1$ of order $p^3$.

I only observed $1$ can have order $p,p^2,p^3$. If its $p^3$ then $\mathbb{Z}/(p^3)$. Otherwise will it be just be $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)\times \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p) \times \mathbb{Z}/(p) \times \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ ?

Comment: Certainly there are more examples, like $(\mathbb{Z}/p) [X]/(X^3)$.

Comment: Maybe the most interesting one is $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)[pX]$.

Comment: Yup, but how to classify all ?

Comment: Such a ring must contain a prime subring, that is, Z/(p). Then you can investigate the homo. from Z/(p)[x] to the original ring.

Comment: This question really needs context.  But I would say: most examples need only one generator over $\mathbb{Z}$, so are quotients of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and the remaining examples are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}/p$, so you can work with a basis.

Comment: @Sky Not quite, the subring generated by $1$ could be $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^3$.

Comment: Sorry I have ignored. But I think this problem can be worked out this way.

Comment: Context: I saw for $p^2$ thats why was thinking how about the case $p^3$ ... and isn't there any concrete form ?